# Create popup with bootstrap and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

This is cshtml

```
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#empmodal">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullName, new { @id = "empName" })
                                    </a>


<div class="ui tiny modal new-employee-modal" id="empmodal">
    <div class="ui placeholder">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my js

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("Details")' /*+ input_index*/;

            $('.modal.new-employee-modal').modal({
                autofocus: false,
                onHidden: function () {
                    $('.modal.new-employee-modal').empty();
                    $('.modal.new-employee-modal').append(
                        `<div class="ui placeholder">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="paragraph">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="paragraph">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="paragraph">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="paragraph">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
        </div>`)
                }
            })
                .modal('show');
            $.get(url).done(function (a) {
                $(".modal.new-employee-modal").html(a);

            });


        });
```

This is my particalview and pop-up in inside

```
 <div class="modal-title-area">
        <div class="modal-name">
            @{ ViewBag.Title = "employee details";
               
                }
        </div>
        <div class="modal-root-page tag-label red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-divider"></div>
    <div class="modal-content-area">
        <div class="box-title"></div>
        <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.FirstName</div>
                <div class="text">@Model.FirstName</div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.JobTitle</div>
                <div class="text">@ViewBag.JobTitle</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.LastName</div>
                <div class="text">@Model.LastName</div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.PositionCode</div>
                <div class="text">@ViewBag.Position</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.BirthDate</div>
                <div class="text">@Model.BirthDate</div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.ClassCode</div>
                <div class="text">@ViewBag.Department</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.Gender</div>
                <div class="text">@Model.Gender.EnumDisplayNameFor()</div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.MobilePhoneNo</div>
                <div class="text">@Model.MobilePhoneNo</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.CompanyEMail</div>
                <div class="text">@Model.CompanyEMail</div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="label">@EmployeeCardRes.FirstEmploymentDate</div>
                <div class="text">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstEmploymentDate)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I try to open popup.When I click on the link, the modal should open and it should fetch the data in the model.I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the examples I've looked at it's pretty much done like this.I need to go to the url I gave in javascript and open a partial view from the controller, that is, the last page I threw.
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>popup modal</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="m-4">
    
    <!-- Large modal -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#largeModal">Large modal</button>

    <div id="largeModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Large Modal</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Add the <code>.modal-lg</code> class on <code>.modal-dialog</code> to create this large modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here instead of large button you can put your link

Answer (score 0):

It is better you insert the complete bootstrap and modal libraries:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

And instead of links, maybe use a `<button></button>`
or define an `onclick` event.